# scrape multiple pages data are overwritten

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, post, scrapy

Data are overwritten and they give the data of only last page how to solve these problem is any solution for these kindly recommend me I've seen several solutions to scrape multiple pages from a website, but couldn't make it work on my code

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy import FormRequest
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    from scrapy.http import Request
    
    class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'test'
        url = 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/'
        
        for x in range(0,5):
            payload='p='+str(x)+'&letterfilter=%D0%90'
            
            headers = {
            'authority': 'advpalata.vrn.ru',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220; ie=yes; stat_id=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220; _ym_uid=1658939896610936176; _ym_d=1658939896; _ym_isad=2; PHPSESSID=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220',
            'origin': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru',
            'referer': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/',
            'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
    
    
            def start_requests(self):
                yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                    url=self.url,
                    method='POST',
                    body=self.payload,
                    headers=self.headers,
                    callback=self.parse_item,
                    )
    
            def parse_item(self, response):
            
                books = response.xpath("//td[@class='name']//a//@href").extract()
                for book in books:
                    absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
                    yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)
                    
            def parse_book(self, response):
                title=response.css("h3::text").get()
                # phone = response.xpath("//div[@class='advocate-right']//p['@umi:field-name=phone']//text()").get()
                # email = response.xpath("//div[@class='advocate-right']//p['@umi:field-name=email']//a//text()").get()
    
            
                yield{
                    'title':title,
                    # 'phone':phone,
                    # 'email':email
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is you needs to use **next()** in yield loop for iteration.

**This code works**

Sorry words and w_pages were hard-cord

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import urllib.parse

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    url = 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers'
    headers = {
        'authority': 'advpalata.vrn.ru',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220; ie=yes; stat_id=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220; _ym_uid=1658939896610936176; _ym_d=1658939896; _ym_isad=2; PHPSESSID=546743b283bb9e3b2e78dabbfb894220',
        'origin': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru',
        'referer': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        words = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ж','З','И','К','Л', 'М','Н','О','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Э','Ю','Я','Все']
        w_pages=[14 , 24, 9 , 19, 11, 0 , 5 , 9 ,  5,39 , 12, 21, 10,  4,  10, 28, 12,  2,  5,  4,  1,  7, 11,  1,  1,  2,  3, 315]
        index = 0
        for word in words:
            pages = list(range(0,w_pages[index]))
            index = index + 1
            x=iter(pages)
            for dummy in pages:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url=self.url,
                    method='POST',
                    body="p={0}&letterfilter={1}".format(next(x),urllib.parse.quote_plus(word)),
                    headers=self.headers, 
                    callback=self.parse
                )

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//td[@class='name']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)
                    
    def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.css("h3::text").get()
        yield{
            'title':title
        }
```

if want to save correct title into json file
add this line in settings.py

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

I got 3151 titles by this code.
I copy here first 10 and last 10 titles

```
{"title": "Алфёрова Людмила Григорьевна"},
{"title": "Александров Юрий Иванович"},
{"title": "Агрба Платон Заурович"},
{"title": "Аветисов Сергей Эдуардович"},
{"title": "Аксенов Дмитрий Михайлович"},
{"title": "Акиньшина Галина Сергеевна"},
{"title": "Ануфриенко Андрей Иванович"},
{"title": "Анищенко Игорь Сергеевич"},
{"title": "Арженых Оксана Сергеевна"},
{"title": "Астанин Владимир Егорович"},
...
{"title": "Щербакова Татьяна Николаевна"},
{"title": "Щербакова Лилия Ивановна"},
{"title": "Щурков Алексей Михайлович"},
{"title": "Щетинина Татьяна Николаевна"},
{"title": "Щукина Валентина Васильевна"},
{"title": "Щетинина Галина Александровна"},
{"title": "Щетинина Ирина Юрьевна"},
{"title": "Ююкин Александр Викторович"},
{"title": "Щербинин Андрей Викторович"},
{"title": "Щербакова Лилия Викторовна"}
```

I referenced two links [yeild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855) and [encoding uni-code](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/)

Comment: thank for helping but these give data of `Все` word only `Bce` word has 3000 data the total data is almost `7000 + data` of all the words

Comment: you are right, I think some page has sub pages. example "Все" & p=2 & СПЕЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ -> "ВЫБОР СПЕЦИАЛИЗАЦИИ" it has 7 sub-pages  and grand child pages (КЛАССИФИКАТОР СПЕЦИАЛЬНОСТИ) 18 pages. So you need to find how to parsing sub pages. Sorry I can't help you I can't read it.